# Using ssh-agent with KDE?

Tags: ssh, kde, ssh-agent

I had this working once before, but for some reason it's not working on my new system.

in `.kde4/Autostart/` I have a symlink to ssh-agent called `01-sshagent` and then a simple script called `02-sshkeys` that looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-add $(find $HOME/.ssh/keys -type f | egrep -v '\.pub$')
```

The problem seems to be that when I startup, ssh-agent is run alright, but KDE doesn't hold onto the output and store it in the environment, so for every Konsole session, I have to run `ps` to find the PID and then manually type:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-YtvdiEtW3065/agent.3065; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=<pidnumber>; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

...just to get it to work, and it does... just in that Konsole window.

I've tried removing the aforementioned symlink and just havining the ssh script look like this:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-agent | sh
/usr/bin/ssh-add $(find $HOME/.ssh/keys -type f | egrep -v '\.pub$')
```

But still, the agent variables aren't in the session and I'm never prompted for the password to my keys.

I'm obviously missing something, but what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My simple solution is to just run one ssh-agent and always keep it running.  You can kill it on log-out if you really want to.  The key is to just use a fixed socket.  Add ssh-agent -a /tmp/$USER.agent to an Autostart script.  Then do "export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/$USER.agent" followed by ssh-add.  Also, you can add that export to your .bashrc, .profile or other shell log-in script and always have access to the agent even when using a remote ssh in.

Comment: It feels like a bit of a hack, but it totally works!  Thanks!

Comment: I started doing this once I realized it's not really less secure than running a per-session agent if I never really log out. The recommended way to use ssh-agent is not in Autostart, but use it kinda like sudo to run startkde. For example, "ssh-agent startkde"  Before startkde runs, SSH_AUTH_SOCK is setup  and when startkde exits, so does ssh-agent.  It's more reliable than depending on Autostart, but trickier to set up correctly. Ubuntu has support to make this easy to do and will even generate a chain of commands like this. Looking at ps, I see "ssh-agent gpg-agent dbus-launch gnome-session"

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, and probably deserves an updated answer. The following *works for me* (Fedora 31 / KDE).

1. Set up KWallet with the default wallet (`kdewallet`) and with the same password as your login password. Ensure it unlocks on login. Arch Wiki has some [info on that](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE_Wallet); in my case I had to uncomment some lines in `/etc/pam.d/sddm`.
2. Create your SSH key (`ssh-keygen`) with whatever password you like (since you're going to use a password manager, it doesn't need to be memorable).
3. Ensure `ssh-add` and `ksshaskpass` are installed.
4. Add an auto-start script like the following:

   ```
   $ cat $HOME/.config/autostart-scripts/ssh
   #!/bin/sh
   SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ksshaskpass ssh-add </dev/null
   ```

   Do `chmod +x` and run it once. Ksshaskpass should ask your SSH password. Tell it to remember the password (this uses KWallet). Run again and notice this time it doesn't ask.

That should be it.

Comment: This still works great with Kbuntu 21.10

Answer (score 1):

According to my observations quote "for some reason it's not working on my new system" stands:

- while upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 (new KDE version 4.11.5)
- with shell tcsh

This happens with my favorite shell during aforementioned upgrade at least twice. Any other shells works fine. This problem has too scant internet coverage, because of tcsh low popularity. So, one of decisions is migrate to zsh. I do it

I dug deeper and found evident cause of error. ssh-agent started by command

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

in file /usr/share/upstart/sessions/ssh-agent.conf by [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/). First, command ssh-agent executad as is and produces output similar to:

```
setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK /tmp/ssh-7AWho81toBZZ/agent.13776;
setenv SSH_AGENT_PID 13783;
echo Agent pid 13783;
```

Second, this output executed by eval and in case of csh we can see:

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 1: eval: setenv: not found
```

in ~/.cache/upstart/ssh-agent.log. This error is due "SHELL looks like csh style" (see ssh-agent(1)).

So, short and exhaustive **answer** is:

- append -s option to ssh-agent invocation command (/usr/share/upstart/sessions/ssh-agent.conf):

  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
- or do not use [csh](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tcsh.1.html)

Comment: How does changing to zsh fix this problem?

Comment: @Michael, I fix my answer. Correct myself: zsh is one of the possible workarounds

Comment: when using csh, use ``ssh-agent -c``, from the man: Generate C-shell commands on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a fan of updating the KDE startup process.  I do the following:

`mkdir ~/.bashrc.d`

Then at the bottom of `.bashrc`

```
for BASHRCFILE in `ls .bashrc.d`; do
    . .bashrc.d/$BASHRCFILE
done;
```

Then each time I reboot, I run this in a terminal:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
echo "export SSH_AGENT_PID=${SSH_AGENT_PID}; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}" > .bashrc.d/ssh-agent
```

Every time you open a new shell, the contents of `.bashrc.d/ssh-agent` get imported into the shell environment.  This is a nice way to inject envronment variables into all your shells.

Comment: Any idea if this will also work with things like Dolphin when connecting with sftp?

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but I still ended up here looking for a solution.

One of the issues in my distro at least is that if you are using GDM, which is Gnome's Display Manager it doesn't care about KDE/Plasma at all and does nothing to make sure it is launched properly with all its configuration utilities.

What you have to do for GDM at least is make sure you include PAM related settings.

You can do this two ways.  You can install both and look at each set of configuration files and compare what is missing, or you can just give what I say a try.  Going with looking at the config files will probably be the best bet into the future if things change, but either way things should be similar.

For the first file you need to edit it is `/etc/pam.d/gdm-autologin`

Inside this file you will need to add 1 line under `@include common-session`

Add this line under the gnome key ring line.

```
session optional        pam_kwallet5.so auto_start
```

The next file you need to edit is `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password`

Inside this file you need to add 1 line under `@include common-auth`

Add this line under the gnome key ring.so line.

```
auth   optional         pam_kwallet5.so
```

That should take care of your login issues if you are using Plasma.

You could probably just include these things in some other way, but this is what worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.

Hope this helps.